# Is JRE 1.6 memory leak in pthread_create?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, pthreads, glibc

```
Environment Info:
OS:
SLES 11 sp1(Linux linux 2.6.32.59-0.7-default #1 SMP 2012-07-13 15:50:56 +0200 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux);
GLIBC:
rpm -qa | grep glibc
glibc-devel-2.11.1-0.17.4
glibc-i18ndata-2.11.1-0.17.4
glibc-32bit-2.11.1-0.17.4
glibc-locale-32bit-2.11.1-0.17.4
glibc-info-2.11.1-0.17.4
glibc-locale-2.11.1-0.17.4
glibc-devel-32bit-2.11.1-0.17.4
glibc-2.11.1-0.17.4;
JRE:
java version "1.6.0_43"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_43-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.14-b01, mixed mode)
JVM Args:
-Xms128m -Xmx128m -XX:MaxPermSize=64m

Problem when the java process runing after a while,resident memory has an increase of 200M.
/proc/${PID}/fd and jstack have no changes.

Then I use gperftools to analyse the memory,as fellow:
time1:
   124.5  31.5%  80.0%    124.5  31.5% pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5
time2:
   162.6  37.3%  81.2%    162.6  37.3% pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5
'pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5' calling increase from 124.5M to 162.6M
```

Is JRE 1.6 memory leak in pthread_create?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is JRE 1.6 memory leak in pthread_create?

It is possible, but I seriously doubt it.

If you `start()` lots of threads and they never terminate, then you *will* leak memory.  However, that's not the fault of `pthread_create`.  The memory leak is (in effect) in your code.

---

Unbounded thread creation is a bad thing in a Java application.  A much better strategy is to use an `ExecutorService` instance with a bounded thread pool ... and let the Java runtime take care of thread creation.

Comment: Yes,I start thread by using ExecutorService.And as described in Environment Info.In time1 and time2,the jstack output is similar.

Comment: @shamokuyuwpz - So what is the issue then?  The "leaked" stack memory is most likely not leaked at all.  It actually belongs to an idle thread in the thread pool.

Comment: The issue is : why the memory of pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5 occupying is increase while the thread numbers is stable?

Comment: @shamokuyuwpz - but are both of those "facts" true?  You haven't provided any *evidence* that the number of threads was constant between those two points.  The point is that you are claiming that there is a major memory leak in thread creation in Java 1.6, but there are no related bug reports that I could find.  The most likely explanation is that you've made a mistake ...

Comment: @shamokuyuwpz - Either way, if you want to move forward on this you will need to create an SSCCE for the problem ... so that other people can (maybe) understand what is going on.  If this is a real JVM bug, then you can include the SSCCE in the bug report.

Comment: Yes,no memory leak in proccess.It just increase slowly,and at last the memory usage is stable.